# Persist views across screen rotation

Tags: android, android-view

New to Android so I'm writing small programs to get familiar with how things work.
What has been giving me a headache so far are views created at runtime in combination with screen rotation.

After having little luck trying to use parcels, I solved the problem by just recreating the views after a rotation.

The program will add the entered text as a TextView to a TableLayout below the EditText.

Is there a better way of solving this? I could not find any "out of the box" methods for doing this.

```
public class MWEActivity extends Activity {
    TableLayout table;
    EditText txtInput;
    ArrayList<String> savedEntry = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        table = (TableLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.table);
        txtInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);

        txtInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        TextView newtext = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        newtext.setText(txtInput.getText());
                        savedEntry.add(newtext.getText().toString());
                        table.addView(newtext);
                        txtInput.setText("");
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putStringArrayList("entry", savedEntry);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("entry") == null){
            savedEntry = new ArrayList<String>();
            savedEntry.add("Return was NULL");
        }else{
            savedEntry = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("entry");
        }

        for(String s : savedEntry){
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText(s);
            table.addView(tv);
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have to disable orientation change like in previous answer, or just rely 
on standard facility. It will pause an then recreate your activity. No extra code is necessary. You can also provide different layouts for different orientations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Knabber: If you are using dynamic fragments, you can use `setRetainInstance(true)` to get much of the benefit of the `android:configChanges` approach, without most of the attendant risks. If you are not using dynamic fragments, you can still use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to move your *data* between the activity instances. In particular, `onSaveInstanceState()` also helps you in other scenarios, beyond configuration changes. Please use one of these approaches.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Knabber: Just accept this one. His answer is correct -- I merely provided clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You can stop the reloading of the activity by putting

```
        android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in the manifest.xml for the activity and implementing onConfigurationChanged.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

If your layout is the  same you should not need to do anything else.

Comment: @Knabber: Actually, this solution sucks. First, it's wrong -- you need more values in your `android:configChanges` list (at least `keyboardHidden`). Second, this approach will fail for all other configuration changes, such as the person putting the device into a dock, unless you list *all* possible configuration changes in `android:configChanges`. Third, this now means you must *manually* reload *every* resource you are using on *every* relevant configuration change, including the resources you implement today and all resources you ever add in the future.